# Too many database queries

Tags: database, queries

My site no longer loads and I can no longer access the control panel. After some investigation, it seems there are requests that are taking too long to load or are stuck. When I try to log into phpMyAdmin to checkout the database, it tells me there are too many connections. Below is a log of the database queries. Thanks for any help with this issue. EE v5.3.2.

| 226373475 | myDB     | xx.xx.xx.16:40736 | database_name_here       | Execute | 220575 | Sending data         | SELECT t.entry_id, t.channel_id, t.forum_topic_id, t.author_id, t.ip_address, t.title, t.url_title, | 0     | 0

| 226373637 | myDB     | xx.xx.xx.16:42320 | database_name_here       | Execute | 220537 | Sending data         | SELECT exp_channel_titles.entry_id as ChannelEntry__entry_id, ChannelEntry_field_id_44.field_id_44 a | 2     | 0

| 226374442 | myDB     | xx.xx.xx.16:50722 | database_name_here       | Execute | 220359 | Sending data         | SELECT exp_channel_titles.entry_id as ChannelEntry__entry_id, ChannelEntry_field_id_44.field_id_44 a | 2     | 0

| 226374499 | myDB     | xx.xx.xx.16:52106 | database_name_here       | Query  | 220345 | Waiting for table level lock | UPDATE `exp_members` SET `last_activity` = 1600719187 WHERE `member_id` = 1             | 0     | 0

| 226374574 | myDB     | xx.xx.xx.16:53182 | database_name_here       | Query  | 220322 | Waiting for table level lock | UPDATE `exp_members` SET `last_activity` = 1600719210 WHERE `member_id` = 1             | 0     | 0

| 226374608 | myDB     | xx.xx.xx.16:53472 | database_name_here       | Query  | 220318 | Waiting for table level lock | UPDATE `exp_members` SET `last_activity` = 1600719215 WHERE `member_id` = 1             | 0     | 0

| 226374667 | myDB     | xx.xx.xx.16:53876 | database_name_here       | Query  | 220306 | Waiting for table level lock | UPDATE `exp_members` SET `last_activity` = 1600719227 WHERE `member_id` = 1             | 0     | 0

| 226374694 | myDB     | xx.xx.xx.16:54124 | database_name_here       | Query  | 220300 | Waiting for table level lock | UPDATE `exp_members` SET `last_activity` = 1600719233 WHERE `member_id` = 1             | 0     | 0

| 226374719 | root       | localhost     | database_name_here       | Query  | 220292 | Waiting for table level lock | explain SELECT t.entry_id, t.channel_id, t.forum_topic_id, t.author_id, t.ip_address, t.title, t.ur | 0     | 0

| 226374724 | myDB     | xx.xx.xx.16:54538 | database_name_here       | Query  | 220290 | Waiting for table level lock | UPDATE `exp_members` SET `last_activity` = 1600719243 WHERE `member_id` = 1             | 0     | 0

| 226409713 | mtbackup     | 72.47.246.12:52577 | database_name_here       | Query  | 213852 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `exp_members`                         | 0     | 0

| 227263391 | myDB     | xx.xx.xx.22:53364 | database_name_here       | Execute | 62966 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT *
FROM (`exp_members` m, `exp_member_groups` g)
WHERE `g`.`site_id` = 1
AND m.group_id = g. | 0     | 0

| 227263413 | myDB     | xx.xx.xx.22:53578 | database_name_here       | Execute | 62963 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT *
FROM (`exp_members` m, `exp_member_groups` g)
WHERE `g`.`site_id` = 1
AND m.group_id = g. | 0     | 0

| 227263949 | myDB     | xx.xx.xx.21:60404 | database_name_here       | Execute | 62838 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT *
FROM (`exp_members` m, `exp_member_groups` g)
WHERE `g`.`site_id` = 1
AND m.group_id = g. | 0     | 0

| 227265302 | myDB     | xx.xx.xx.21:44974 | database_name_here       | Execute | 62590 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT *
FROM (`exp_members` m, `exp_member_groups` g)
WHERE `g`.`site_id` = 1
AND m.group_id = g. | 0     | 0

| 227265854 | myDB     | xx.xx.xx.21:51338 | database_name_here       | Execute | 62490 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT *
FROM (`exp_members` m, `exp_member_groups` g)
WHERE `g`.`site_id` = 1
AND m.group_id = g. | 0     | 0

| 227266040 | myDB     | xx.xx.xx.21:53146 | database_name_here       | Execute | 62459 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT *
FROM (`exp_members` m, `exp_member_groups` g)
WHERE `g`.`site_id` = 1
AND m.group_id = g. | 0     | 0

| 227266310 | myDB     | xx.xx.xx.21:55624 | database_name_here       | Execute | 62403 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT *
FROM (`exp_members` m, `exp_member_groups` g)
WHERE `g`.`site_id` = 1
AND m.group_id = g. | 0     | 0

| 227269701 | myDB     | xx.xx.xx.21:56208 | database_name_here       | Execute | 61775 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT *
FROM (`exp_members` m, `exp_member_groups` g)
WHERE `g`.`site_id` = 1
AND m.group_id = g. | 0     | 0

| 227270694 | myDB     | xx.xx.xx.21:36758 | database_name_here       | Execute | 61592 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT *
FROM (`exp_members` m, `exp_member_groups` g)
WHERE `g`.`site_id` = 1
AND m.group_id = g. | 0     | 0

| 227271250 | myDB     | xx.xx.xx.21:43566 | database_name_here       | Execute | 61440 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT *
FROM (`exp_members` m, `exp_member_groups` g)
WHERE `g`.`site_id` = 1
AND m.group_id = g

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your server?

Comment: I can't. It's a shared server.

Comment: Even on a shared server your host should be able to reboot it, worth asking.